# i want to display list of an array from react but it's not showing when i think i did everything right?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, arraylist, react-hooks

i want to display list of an array from react but it's not showing when i think i did everything right? Please where im i wrong here

below is the code

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
   
  const [items , setItems] = useState([{
       id:1,
       text:'simple 1'
  },
  {
    id:1,
       text:'simple 2'
  },
  {
    id:1,
    text:'simple 3'
  },

])

  return (
    <div className="App">
    
    {items.map((item) => (
      <h1>{items.text}</h1>
    ))}


     <h1>Hello from React js</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `<h1>{items.text}</h1>` should be `<h1>{item.text}</h1>`. And add a unique `key` prop

Comment: oh, thank you so much i totally forgot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're using **items.text** instead of **item.text**

```
{items.map((item) => (
  <h1>{item.text}</h1>
))}
```

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-hugle-3vk12?file=/src/App.js) its work perfectly